# PHP - Mysql how show items from a DB related to specific column

Tags: php, mysql

Hello below some info about my problem

My_DB name is: **products**

Table name is: **spec_products**

Columns in spec_products are:

**id|sku|brand|title|price**

How can i show (with php) only items from the brand column?
In particular it's a piece of code that i need insert in sidebar of single product page that show products correlated to the brand

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MySQL query:

Select brand From spec_products;

Answer (score 0):

use clause distinct to avoid duplicate values if more of one of your products have the same brand

```
select dintinct brand from spec_products
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to display only the brands from the table. If this is the case, it is a simple Selecting Data from MySQL that you would have got by simple search on Google.

You can refer to a W3School tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

You can simply run a SELECT query for brands:
`SELECT brand FROM spec_products`

Comment: You can do a `SELECT * FROM spec_products WHERE brand="BRAND_NAME_HERE"` to show all products of a particular brand

Comment: @user3909667 how can i display in php?

Comment: Did you refer to the W3School tutorial I posted. I think it must be clear on how to `echo` mysql result